# How to beat Pig Bang 1-20

Tags: angry-birds-space

I've been trying to get 3 stars on level 20 for a while and I can't figure it out.  I get more points if I send the bird flying directly through the pigs instead of just bursting their bubble things but it's not enough.  The grass stuff on the moon isn't enough points to justify using another bird to destroy it.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting 3 stars with a single bird used to burst all three bubbles? That gives me around 36k points, which is enough for 3 stars

Comment: @YiJiang My highest is 36145, two stars. It's the Android version so maybe there's a difference if you're on another platform?

Comment: Something must be up because I just got 36140 to test and received 3 stars on the iOS version.

Comment: @Johnathan No, I'm playing on a tablet running 3.2 Honeycomb. There shouldn't be any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been retrying this level now for a few times just to check. Using just one bird, it gave me 2 stars once and 3 stars all the other times. That was apparently unrelated to me bursting their bubbles as opposed to hitting them directly, and independent of me shaving some grass. So I guess there's just some fluke - I recommend you just try it a few more times.

As a way of adding variety to your tries, try shooting into them a different direction than the one you've been trying - you can shoot into them from below as well as above. It makes shaving the grass or colliding with the moon easier.

Comment: I tried it from below a few times instead of from above, and the bird shaved some stuff off for a 36250 score which was enough :) thanks very much :)

Comment: I get a message "Please login or register to vote for this post."  I saw you need 15 points to vote but I think that message is wrong, since I'm obviously logged in? Not registered though...

Comment: @Johnathan this site keeps track of your "reputation", but to access the privileges they entail you need to both be an actual registered user and have more reputation than the threshold. For voting up, it is indeed 15 reputation, so you can't do it just yet, even if you were registered. Thank you for trying, though! :)